# Trigger ajax with space key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My function valueS() doesn't work for some reason, it won't trigger the ajax function on the bottom... for some reason bind('change keyup input') doesn't trigger when a space is added.

How do I fix the function valueS() to trigger the bottom function?

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    switch(event.which){
        case 32:
            if(!$('input').is(':focus')){
               event.preventDefault();
               valueS();
            }
            break;
        //other cases not shown here
    }


function valueS(){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('id1').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? "" : value;
    document.getElementById('id1').value = "" + value + " ";
}


$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('#id1').bind('change keyup input', function(ev) {
        if(/\s/.test($(this).val())){
            // removes space
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[\s]/g, '');

            // submits ajax
            if(this.value.length>0)
                ajax_post();

            // clears input
            $('input[id=id1]').val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will call your function...

```
$('#id1').trigger("change");
```

None of the bound events would be triggered by you changing the value programatically.  You can trigger them manually using the `trigger` function.